# Numexpr: How to use "local_dict" and "global_dict"?

Tags: python, numpy, numexpr

I have been experimenting and trying to learn the [Numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/wiki/UsersGuide) package. Examples on how to use it are sparse at best. Can someone please give me a quick example on how to use the "local_dict" and "global_dict" arguments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following examples may clarify it a little. First set up the scene like this:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

a = np.arange(10)
b = np.arange(10, 20)
c = np.arange(20, 30)
```

**No `dict`**

```
>>> def f0(a, b) :
...     a, b = 2 * a, 3 * b
...     return ne.evaluate('2*a + 3*b + c')
...
>>> f0(a, b)
array([110, 124, 138, 152, 166, 180, 194, 208, 222, 236])
>>> 4 * a + 9 * b + c
array([110, 124, 138, 152, 166, 180, 194, 208, 222, 236])
```

When you run it like this, `a` and `b`are the local variables, and `c`is the global variable, as expected.

**`local_dict`**

```
>>> def f1(a, b) :
...     a, b = 2 * a, 3 * b
...     return ne.evaluate('2*a + 3*b + c',
...                        local_dict={'c' : np.arange(30, 40)})
...
>>> f1(a, b)
array([ 60,  66,  72,  78,  84,  90,  96, 102, 108, 114])
>>> 2*a + 3 * b + np.arange(30, 40)
array([ 60,  66,  72,  78,  84,  90,  96, 102, 108, 114])
```

Because we have redefined `local_dict`, `a` and `b` no longer show up there as local variables, so the value of the global ones is used instead. And because `c` now is defined as a local variable, the value of the global one is ignored.

**`global_dict`**

```
>>> def f2(a, b) :
...     a, b = 2 * a, 3 * b
...     return ne.evaluate('2*a + 3*b + c',
...                        global_dict= {'c' : np.arange(30, 40)})
...
>>> f2(a, b)
array([120, 134, 148, 162, 176, 190, 204, 218, 232, 246])
>>> 4 * a + 9 * b + np.arange(30, 40)
array([120, 134, 148, 162, 176, 190, 204, 218, 232, 246])
```

In this case, `a` and `b` are taken from the default local dictionary, and the new `c` is taken in place of the original global one.

Comment: Oohhh! I thought it was some business about assigning functions as variables (i.e. `mul=operator.mul`). Thanks!

Comment: But why would you ever want to use these?